# Threading nested for loops

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I've been looking for a while for a similar question but without any success. I don't know how to optimize some code in cocoa to use all available cores of CPU (I don't want to use GPU at the moment). Below is simple sample of code with case I mean:

```
int limA = 1000;
int limB = 1000;
unsigned short tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  for (int a = 0; a < limA; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < limB; b++) {
      tmp = [[array objectAtIndex:(a*b)] unsignedShortValue];
      c_array[a*limB+b] += tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

assume that array and c_array is properly initialized etc... But as you can see, if we have many iterations (in this case: 10^10) it takes some time to execute this code. I thought that maybe It is simple possibility to execute this code in few threads, but how to synchronize c_array? What is the best way to improve time execution of this kind of code in objective-c? Maybe it could be done this way that iterations 0-2499 of most external for loop would be executed in thread 1 and 2500-4999 thread 2 etc... ? I know that this is silly way but I don't need "real time" performance... any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you are not simply adding 10000 times `tmp` to `c_array` instead of looping 10000 times in the outer loop? The outer loop seems to be redundant.

Comment: Is the second loop really necessary here or is this not really the actual code that you would like to execute?

Comment: @Roshan It is not the actual code i would like to execute. My code is quite complex and it would bring nothing useful to my question, so I simplified it to the code above and agree that it is too infantile but, I think it shows the problem. In my "real code" There is no possibility to avoid outer loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, follow @Catfish_Man's suggestion, except for the parallelism part.

For the parallelism, here are my ideas:

1. The outmost loop is meaningless. Just use `10000 * tmp` instead of `tmp`.
2. Since the segments of target array to be written to are strictly disjoint for different `a` values, the second level of loop can be easily parallelized. In fact, it also applies to `b`. But if we also parallelize over `b` the calculation unit left in the body will be too small for the splitting of the work load to be useful.

Code:

```
int limA = 1000;
int limB = 1000;
short *tmp_array = calloc(limA * limB, sizeof(short));
int tmp_idx = 0;
for (NSNumber *num in array) {
    tmp_array[tmp_idx++] = [num unsignedShortValue];
}
dispatch_apply(limA, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t a) {
    for (int b = 0; b < limB; b++) {
        tmp = ;
        c_array[a*limB+b] += 1000 * tmp_array[a*b];
    }
});
free(tmp_array);
```

Answer (score 8):

A few suggestions:

Do an initial pass over the array to extract all the shorts from their object wrappers:

```
short *tmp_array = calloc(limA * limB, sizeof(short));
int tmp_idx = 0;
for (NSNumber *num in array) {
    tmp_array[tmp_idx++] = [num unsignedShortValue];
}
```

This has several benefits. You go from 10^10 method calls to 10^6, your inner loop stops being opaque to the compiler (it can't "see through" method calls), and your inner loop gets smaller and more likely to fit in the instruction cache.

Try to linearize access patterns. Right now you're doing 'strided' access, since the index is being multiplied each time. If you can rearrange the data in `tmp_array` so that elements that are processed sequentially are also sequential in the array, you should get much better performance (since each access to the array is loading a full cache line, which is 64 bytes on most processors).

Getting a benefit out of parallelism is likely to be tricky. You could try replacing the outer loop with:

```
dispatch_apply(10000, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t i) {

});
```

and the += in the inner loop with `OSAtomicAdd`, but my suspicion is that your speed is going to be dominated by memory accesses anyway, and adding more processors to the mix will just lead to them stepping on each other's toes (i.e. processor 0 loads `c_array[1500]` so that it knows what to add `tmp` to, which actually loads the cache line covering [1500-1531], then processor 1 writes to `c_array[1512]`, invalidating that entire cache line and forcing it to be re-read). Also, I'm pretty sure you'd need to store 32 bit values in c_array to do that, since you'd be using OSAtomicAdd32 (there's no OSAtomicAdd16).

At the very least, if you're going to parallelize, then you need to figure out how to divide the work into non-overlapping chunks of 32 elements of `c_array` (i.e. 64 bytes), so that you can avoid contention. Dividing up the ranges of the array should also let you avoid needing to use atomic add operations.

(edit)

Check out an0's answer for some practical suggestions for parallelizing this, rather than this discussion of why the naive parallelization won't work :)

Comment: Thank you for great suggestions! But as you said, anO's answer is more practical so I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

First, follow @Catfish_Man's suggestions. Then follow @an0's suggestions. Then do this as well:

```c
// ...
short *tmp_array = calloc(limA * limB, sizeof(short));
unsigned short (*unsignedShortValueIMP)(id, SEL) = class_getMethodImplementation([NSNumber class], @selector(unsignedShortValue));
void * (*objectAtIndexIMP)(id, SEL, NSUInteger) = class_getMethodImplementation(array.class, @selector(objectAtIndex:));
NSUInteger n = array.count;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    void *obj = objectAtIndexIMP(array, @selector(objectAtIndex:), i);
    tmp_array[i] = unsignedShortValueIMP((__bridge id)obj, @selector(unsignedShortValue));
}
// ...
```

By lifting the `IMP`s out of Objective-C, you bypass all the overhead of the message dispatch machinery and allow the compiler to "see through" the calls; while these selectors are part of Foundation and can't be inlined, removing the extra levels of indirection improves the holy heck out of the branch prediction and prefetching machinery in the CPU cores. In addition, by using a raw C for loop instead of Objective-C's array enumeration, AND not forcing the opacity of objc_msgSend() on the compiler, you allow Clang's loop unwinding and vectorization optimizers to work.

@Catfish_Man may be able to tell me this is an outmoded optimization no longer worth doing, but as far as I'm aware, it's still a win for massive repetitions of calling the same methods like this.

Final note: My code assumes ARC, so uses `void *` and a bridge cast instead of `id` on the `objectAtIndex:` `IMP` to bypass the extra implicit `retain`/`release` pair. This is evil shadow hackery, disabling ARC for the file in question is a better solution, and I should be ashamed of myself.